# angular counting 2 chars for newline in text area

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am counting characters in text area and showing remaining characters. I am also using ng-trim. But new line is occupying 2 chars and i am able to minus only one from length. how to work around this?

```
<textarea ng-model="desc" ng-init = "desc= ''" ng-trim="false" placeholder="Type your description here"  maxlength="1000" role="textarea"></textarea>
<p>Characters remaining: {{1000-desc.length}} </p>
```

Can I count newlines and minus along with length. If I can then how can I get the no of new lines here in html?

Comment: why are you using `utFormData.updateDescription` instead of `desc`?

Comment: sorry copy paste error

Comment: what's your task? do you want to exclude all newlines from the characters count?

Comment: It did not work. If i count new lines then I can minus them once again.

Comment: did you see my updated answer? can you be more specific about what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all whitespaces, including newlines from the characters count, you can define a function on the controller to do that:

```
  $scope.desc = '';
  $scope.length = 0;
  $scope.$watch('desc', function(value) {
      $scope.length = value.replace(/\s/g, '').length;
  });
```

And then simply use it like that in html:

```
<textarea ng-model="desc" placeholder="Type your description here"  maxlength="1000" role="textarea"></textarea>
<p>Characters remaining: {{length}}</p>
```

See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/p0TEcyJfsiJszDBL2wh1?p=preview)

Comment: sorry I cannot understand -1. will try though.

Comment: @AbelD, _new line is occupying 2 chars_ - actually it occupies one char. [Try here](https://plnkr.co/edit/p0TEcyJfsiJszDBL2wh1?p=preview) putting `1` and then pressing `Enter` and then `2`. You'll see 3 characters length.